# Inno Setup execute second app only if first app finished

Tags: installation, inno-setup

In my installation script i need to execute 2 applications during the installation process, but i am need to execute the second application only if the first app is finished, how do this?

Comment: Yes, i know this, but if i put: 
 [Run]
Filename: "{tmp}\app1.exe"; Flags: waituntilterminated; StatusMsg: "Instalando"; Components: CCCP
Filename: "{tmp}\app2.exe"; Flags: waituntilterminated; StatusMsg: "Instalando"; Components: CCCP    

The 2 apps are executed at same time, i need to execute the first app and only execute the second app after the first app are finished.

Comment: That could mean that the app1.exe is not the real process, but only an unpacker and trigger of some other process and when it triggers this process it terminates what allows to run app2.exe. In this case you should unpack app1.exe to get the real installer which will run till the end of it's installation process.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the only way i found to do this was create a .bat file to control the execution order. In the iss script at [RUN] section i´m call a .bat file to control correctly the execution order, the .bat file contents is:

```
echo [Init app1...]
echo ATTENTION!!! Dont close this.
echo .......  
cd app1
start app1.bat %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
pause
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto FailStart
cd ..\..
echo [Init app2...]
echo ......  
echo ...... 
echo ATTENTION!!! Dont close this.
echo ...... 
echo ......  
cd app2
start app2.bat %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
pause
goto Leave

:FailStart
echo Error in installation proccess... %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
goto Leave

:Leave
echo Finished, press any key...
```

This solves the problem for now. But it's not an elegant solution.
If anyone knows other "ways" to do this, please post.

Thanks everyone.